# Make a rpm package from the cpan compatible tree?

Tags: perl, rpm, packaging, cpan

I always make my perl module following the CPAN-complient tree.  I would like to use this tree to create a rpm file I could install on a hundreth servers.

Is it possible to make a rpm package with `ExtUtils::MakeMaker`?

Where could a 'helloworld' procedure be found?

I browsed the internet and found the program (http://search.cpan.org/~sbeck/cpantorpm-1.00/cpantorpm)

```
 cpantorpm [option] MODULE
```

I cannot understand what kind of module is `MODULE` : is it a cpan module on a cpan repository, a cpan module in a file system, a installed cpan module (then I have to do `make && make test && make install` at least ones on a distant server) or a installed perl module?

Thank for your indications.

Answer (score 0):

As [seen in the cpantorpm docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/SBECK/cpantorpm-1.00/cpantorpm#OBTAIN-THE-PERL-MODULE):

> The perl module may be obtained in a number of different ways. The perl module may exist on local disk either as an archive file or a directory, or it can be retrieved from a URL or from CPAN.
>
> For example, any of the following ways could be used:
>
> ```
> cpantorpm Foo::Bar
> cpantorpm http://some.host.com/some/path/Foo-Bar-1.00.tar.gz
> cpantorpm /tmp/Foo-Bar-1.00.tar.gz
> cpantorpm /tmp/Foo-Bar-1.00
> ```